# How to access 2 keys with 1 command in python dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, scipy

I am trying to load some data from a `.mat` file with scipy's `io.loadmat()`. The function basically returns a dictionary containing all the data from the file. And if I just want to get one value from the data file, I can do something like `val_a = io.loadmat(filename)['val_a']`. But now I'd like to take 2 values out. Can I also achieve this with only one command? Or do I have to first assign the dictionary to a variable and then get the two values one by one?

Like

```
raw_data = io.loadmat(filename)
val_a = raw_data['val_a']
val_b = raw_data['val_b']
```

But what I am looking for is something like

`val_a, val_b = io.loadmat(filename)['val_a', 'val_b']`

By doing so I hope to avoid unnecessary data from the file occupying my memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.x, you may use below *List Comprehension* to achieve this in one line as:

```
my_keys = ['val_a', 'val_b']  # List of keys you want to fetch

val_a, val_b = [my_dict[key] for my_dict in [io.loadmat(filename)] for key in my_keys]
#        wrapped `dict` inside `list` in order to allow your     ^
#        dict available within the *list comorehension*
```

Sample Example:

```
>>> my_keys = ['a', 'b']

>>> [my_dict[key] for my_dict in [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd':4}] for key in my_keys]
[1, 2]   # returned values corresponding to 'a' , 'b'

# `my_dict` can't be referenced outside the scope
>>> my_dict
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'my_dict' is not defined
```

*PS: The above code will execute on the Python 2.x too, but there will be memory leakage for the variables defined within the list comprehension. Which means, reference to `my_dict` will be available outside the list comprehension consuming the memory.*

Comment: The temporary variable here is the `my_dict` in the list comprehension, though (and on Python 2, that temporary variable will leak and keep the dict alive for the duration of the enclosing scope). It *is* a one-liner, at least, although it's pretty bulky and easy to screw up - for example, if you accidentally switch the clauses in the list comprehension, it'll still run but you'll read the file twice.

Comment: I missed the Python 2.x leakage issue, added it to the answer now. Thanks! Regarding the issue with screwing up thing, if the code is in correct, it will always gonna screw up something "big" or "small" :D

Answer (score 8):

You say

> By doing so I hope to avoid unnecessary data from the file occupying my memory

If your goal is to avoid reading parts of the file you're not interested in, then tell SciPy not to read those parts by providing a [`variable_names` argument](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html) saying which parts to read:

```
raw_data = scipy.io.loadmat(filename, variable_names=['val_a', 'val_b'])
val_a = raw_data['val_a']
val_b = raw_data['val_b']
```

Without using `variable_names`, the best you could do would be to get rid of your references to the dict after extracting the parts you're interested in, and let Python reclaim the memory:

```
raw_data = scipy.io.loadmat(filename)
val_a = raw_data['val_a']
val_b = raw_data['val_b']
del raw_data
```

There's no syntax to extract two values from a dict in one go.